# upstart service not starting?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I built nginx from source (I have need for features not available in the version distributed by Ubuntu), and needed to either create a SysV-type service script, or an Upstart script. I went the Upstart route, thinking it would be easier:

```
# nginx - HTTP server.

description "nginx"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
expect fork

env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/luajit-2.0/lib
exec /opt/nginx-1.5.12/sbin/nginx
```

This does not work. `nginx` dies nearly immediately, along with, oddly, a lot of other services:

```
[ 2466.050214] init: nginx-1.5.12 main process (8615) terminated with status 2
[ 2466.050224] init: nginx-1.5.12 main process ended, respawning
[ 2581.872143] init: upstart-udev-bridge main process (398) terminated with status 1
[ 2581.872154] init: upstart-udev-bridge main process ended, respawning
[ 2581.872288] init: upstart-socket-bridge main process (536) terminated with status 1
[ 2581.872296] init: upstart-socket-bridge main process ended, respawning
[ 2581.872388] init: upstart-file-bridge main process (937) terminated with status 1
[ 2581.872395] init: upstart-file-bridge main process ended, respawning
```

Despite the "`respawning`", `nginx` does *not* get respawned by Upstart (near as I can tell, when a service dies, Upstart will log that it is respawning it and then proceed to do nothing at all). Upstart appears to believe the service is running (`service nginx-1.5.12 start` gives an error), so to actually start it, I need to first `stop` it, and *then* `start` it. Otherwise, it starts just fine.

I tried adding some debugging to the `exec` line,

```
exec (cd /tmp && mkdir -p nginx-logs && chmod 777 nginx-logs) && /opt/nginx-1.5.12/sbin/nginx > /tmp/nginx-logs/stdout.log 2>/tmp/nginx-logs/stderr.log
```

It *still* fails to start, but more interestingly, `/tmp/nginx-logs` is never created. Again, running `service … stop` followed by `service … start` works just fine, and at that point, `nginx-logs` is created. This seems to indicate that the line is valid. This is running as root. `/tmp` is world-writable. The directories are absolute. Near as I can tell, Upstart is not actually executing the `exec` line.

In all cases, the `exec` line runs fine by hand. Manually restarting the service works fine. What's going on here?